# Switch function input not working (C++)

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am fairly new to programming, so I apologize if this is a very noobish question. I am in the process of creating just a basic, multiple-choice type game, but I have run into a problem. When I execute my code in the switch loop (in void shop()) I get a constant "This is not a valid option. Please try again" even when I input 1, 2, 3 or 4. If you'd help me out it'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

 using namespace std;

 bool stoleSomething = false;
 string choice = " "; //we will use this choice to manipulate leaving buildings and what-not

void shop(void);
void arena(void);
void inn(void);

int main(){

cout << "You enter the town and see three main areas: the Arena, the Shop and the Inn\n";
cout << "Where do you want to go? Type the name of the location that you want to go - (*no caps* 'arena', 'shop' or 'inn'): \n";

while (choice != "arena" && choice != "shop" && choice != "inn"){
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == "arena"){
        arena();
    }
    else if (choice == "shop"){
        shop();
    }
    else if (choice == "inn"){
        inn();
    }
    else{
        cout << "That is not a valid choice, please try again. \n";
    }
}

system("pause");
}



void shop(){
int choice_shop = 0;
static int isDrunk = 0;

cout << "Here are the things that you can do in the shop: \n";
cout << "1. Have a drink \n";
cout << "2. Repair equipment \n";
cout << "3. Steal something \n";
cout << "4. Leave \n";

while (choice_shop != 4){
    cout << "Enter the option number of the action that you want to take: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice_shop){
    case 1: cout << "You feel a bit more tipsy. \n";
        isDrunk += 1;
        break;
    case 2: cout << "your equipment is fully repaired. \n";
        break;
    case 3: cout << "You hear the shop owner yell at you, and you become frightened; you cannot enter the shop again. \n";
        stoleSomething = true;
        choice = " ";
        break;
    case 4: choice = " ";
    default: cout << "That is not a valid option. Please try again. \n";
    }
    if (isDrunk == 5){
        cout << "You have drunk so much that you finally black out. \n";
        cout << "You wake up just outside of the town. \n";
        choice = " ";
    }
}

 }

 void arena(){
//these will be filled later
 }

 void inn(){
//this will be filled later
 }
```

Comment: You cannot have `choice` shared between function scopes. Make it global or being a parameter instead,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `while` loop and a `switch` statement based on `choice_shop` which remains initialized to `0`.

```
int choice_shop = 0;
// choice_shop never altered
    while (choice_shop != 4) {
        //  choice_shop never altered
        switch (choice_shop) {
             //  choice_shop never altered
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh my goodness. I'm such a chump! When I changed the local variable "choice" to "choice_shop" I forgot to change the variable names in the switch statement! Thanks so much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

choice_shop is set to 0 and you never altered it. So its always the default case for Switch(choice_shop).
Did you actually mean to use 'cin>>choice_shop' inside void shop()???

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask the user to modify your choice_shop variable before you enter